# Problemas con relaciones en Laravel 8: Attempt to read property xxxx on null

Tags: mysql, laravel, blade

Estoy con un problema sencillo pero no sé qué pasa. Tengo tres tablas *well*, *well_down_times* y la otra *well_causes*; cada *well_downtime*, debe y tiene una causa asociada y un *well* asociado.
El modelo *WellDownTime* es el siguiente:

nombre tablas en mysql

- *wells*
- *well_causes*
- *well_down_times*

```
class WellDownTime extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'well_id',
        'fecha',
        'horas', //id tanque
        'well_cause_id',
        'agua_perdido_mt3',
        'oil_perdido_mt3',
        'gas_perdido_mt3',
        'obs',
        'estado'

    ];
    public static function search($query)
    {
        return empty($query) ? static::query()
        : static::join('wells', 'wells.id', '=', 'well_down_times.well_id')
            ->select('well_down_times.*','wells.pozo')
            ->where('fecha', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('pozo', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')                
            ->orWhere('obs', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');                
                  
    }
    protected $casts = [
        'fecha' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
    ];

    //me retorne correctamente nombre del pozo (well) 
    public function well(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Well::class);
    }
     //no me retorna la causa
    public function wellcause(){
      return $this->belongsTo(WellCause::class);
     
    }
```

en la vista (una tabla) pongo

```
$welldowntime->well->pozo //y me retorna nombre del pozo 
$welldowntime->wellcause->causa //error me dice Attempt to read property "causa" on null
```

Los registros de prueba que tengo todos tienen una causa que existe en tabla causa:

Modelo Well

```
class Well extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'area_id',
        'pozo', //string 15
        'well_formation_id',
        'cap_iv_nombre',
        'latitud',
        'longitud',
        'cord_x',
        'coor_y',
        'profundidad',
        'perfo_ini',
        'perfo_fin',
        'termi_ini',
        'termi_fin',
        'well_state_id' //PE=produccion efectiva, PT=parado transitorio, PE=parado en estudio 
    ];

    public static function search($query)
    {
        return empty($query) ? static::query()
            : static::where('pozo', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('cap_iv_nombre', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('well_formation_id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');

    }

   
   public function WellState(){
        return $this->hasOne("App\Models\WellState");
    }
 
    public function well_state() {
        return $this->belongsTo(WellState::class);
    }

    public function WellFormation(){
        return $this->hasOne("App\Models\WellFormation");
    }
  
    public function well_formation() {
        return $this->belongsTo(WellFormation::class);
    }

    public function WellControl(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\WellControl");
  
    }
  
    public function WellIntervention(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\WellIntervention");
  
    }
```

modelo WellCause:

```
class WellCause extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'causa',
        'WellCauseCategory_id',
        'descrip'
    ];

 
 
}
```

Migraciones

```
  //migracion weeldowntime
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('well_down_times', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('well_id')->constrained();
            $table->date('fecha');  
            $table->integer('horas');  
            $table->foreignId('well_cause_id')->constrained();
            $table->double('agua_perdido_mt3', 7,2)->default(0); 
            $table->double('oil_perdido_mt3', 7,2)->default(0); 
            $table->double('gas_perdido_mt3', 7,2)->default(0);   
            $table->boolean('estado')->default(false);   
            $table->text('descrip');               
  
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
  //migracion wellcauses
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('well_causes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('causa',100);
            $table->foreignId('well_cause_categorie_id')->constrained();
            $table->string('descrip',200);                
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, puedes agregar tus tablas y modelos?

Comment: agregado modelos y nombre tablas

Comment: Pero hacen falta las tablas, lo importante ahí es también poder ver los nombres que le das a cada columna para saber si la relación tiene algo que no está bien. Es decir, agrega lo que tienes en las migraciones por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Al usar relaciones en laravel es importante ver los nombres que se le dan a cada columna foranea

En tu modelo `WellDownTime` en el método `wellcause()` tienes lo siguiente

```
return $this->belongsTo(WellCause::class);
```

Las relaciones `belongsTo` tienen 3 parámetros: `Modelo`, `columna_foranea`, `columna_interna` y tanto `columna_foranea` como `columna_interna` son opcionales. Su estructura es la siguiente:

```
return $this->belongsTo(Modelo::class, 'columna_foranea', 'columna_interna');
```

Si únicamente se ingresa el parámetro del modelo entonces Laravel automáticamente intenta "adivinar" el nombre de la columna foránea donde se va a crear la relación y la regla que utiliza laravel es `modelo_id`

En mi opinión, es mejor siempre utilizar los 3 parámetros para evitar errores y para que siempre tengas en cuenta la relación que estás creando

Según la información que pusiste acerca de tus migraciones y tus modelos, la forma de hacer la relación sería:

```
return $this->belongsTo(WellCause::class, 'well_cause_id', 'id');
```

Comment: Gracias, sirvió